# Examples of algebraic surfaces of general type with non ample canonical class

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am interested in the ampleness or nefness of the canonical divisor on a surface of general type. I know many examples (most complete intersections except for some special ones that are either rational surfaces or K3 surfaces) of those with ample canonical class, but none with a canonical class that is not ample but only nef. Are there any explicit examples?

I have heard that the minimal resolution of a projective surface with only rational singularities may give such an example but I am unsure as to how to compute this case.

For me a surface of general type is a minimal surface whose canonical divisor is nef and whose square is strictly greater than zero.

Comment: If you require $K$ to be nef, but you exclude cases where it is ample, then I think the examples you mention are basically all there is.